# Who is the elf/half-elf woman on the cover of "A Grand Tour of the Realms"?

Tags: forgotten-realms, adnd-1e, adnd-2e, content-identification

Besides the (in)famous <s>Gandalf</s> Elminster and <s>Aragorn</s> Drizzt, who is the elf/half-elf lady on the cover of *A Grand Tour of the Realms*?

[image]

Comment: I've gone ahead and also-tagged it with 1e because if memory serves, that's also the cover image in the 1e product. Will be able to double-check my physical copy tomorrow.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to say Arilyn Moonblade. That book uses the same cover art as *Realms of Valor*, which is a collection of D&D short stories. The back of *Realms of Valor* states

> From the secret annals of Realms history come eleven never-before-published tales of valor, featuring the greatest heroes of that magical world—Drizzt Do'Urden, Arilyn Moonblade, Adon, Elminster of Shadowdale, Jander Sunstar, and many others—told by your favorite authors, including: R. A. Salvatore, Ed Greenwood, Douglas Niles, Troy Denning, Christie Golden, and others.

Plus the image fits closely with the cover of [*Elfshadow*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19855.Elfshadow) on which she is featured.